# How to regain lost windows boot loader?

Tags: fedora, boot, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I reinstalled Fedora on my PC. When it launched, I noticed it doesn't have a windows 10 entry in grub. Now, after a bit of research, I believe I had deleted my windows boot loader (partition) because I can't even find it in my BIOS.

I'm gonna be thankful for even remotely pointing me or naming the problem which I can't even google.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If you deleted ESP & /efi/Microsoft folder you have to use your Windows repair flash drive. If BIOS and you deleted the boot partition you can use your Windows repair flash drive and install Windows boot files & add boot flag to the "c:drive" partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to oldfred, I figured my laptop was using UEFI, and it turned out I had completely deleted both Microsoft Reserved Partition and Windows' EFI system partition. This [guide](http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/) was immensely helpful.

For me the solution was to make some space with GParted **before** the primary Windows partition on my hard drive, then recreate EFI system partition and MRP with Windows Repair flash drive, recreate the BCD and reassign the bootloader in my BIOS settings.